# Create a temporary file in /public for Meteor app

Tags: meteor

I need to create temporary files in the /public folder. 
Why? I need to generate small static .html snippets to avoid to call database every time when user refresh the page.

I made this code:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    const fs = require('fs');

    Meteor.methods({

        generateFile() {

            const fileName = 'denis.txt';

            let datapath = process.env.PWD + '/public/files/' + fileName;

            if (Meteor.settings.environment === 'production') { 
                let meteorRoot = fs.realpathSync( process.cwd() + '/../' );
                let publicPath = meteorRoot + '/web.browser/app/files/';
                datapath = publicPath + fileName;
            }

            fs.writeFile(datapath, 'JUST SIMPLE TEXT', 
                function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    console.log('Done!');
                }
            );
        }
    });
}
});
```

So I created a forlder in /public/files.

On localhost it woks perfect. I can access the file like http://localhost:4000/files/denis.txt

On Galaxy hosting I see that it works and I get 'Done!' response in the log.

[image]

But when I try to get in touch the file like www.mysite.com/files/denis.txt It cannot be found there.

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks! :)

Comment: The simple answer is that the file system in Galaxy is probably read only. It is not recommended to write data to /public, you should use an S3 bucket, or have things in the db

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to find out. Everywhere I read that it is not recommended, but not prohibited. So I am trying to find out on my own. Any official sources? :)

Comment: You have to take special steps to make your local file system writable, you then have the problem that your docker container contains state information (ie the files you created), and you therefore can't spin up more docker containers to deal with the load. You can decide whether to follow the recommendations or keep swimming against the tide :)

Comment: I will save data I need in a collection, so generate html-files. I think it must work well. Do not think that it will be an issue. :)

Comment: I think you are making a wrong assumption, namely that calling the database is slower than calling the filesystem. Furthermore, you don't even need to call the database each time if you just store/cache the content in memory. So I would go with that dynamic approach. If necessary, you can create a server-side route to serve that content.